# Shall I set a column on NULL for optional values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using a SQL Server database, I'm working on a real estate website.

I have a table listing the properties with a column called `SIZE`.

A user can optionally input a `SIZE` value for a property (only integral and positive numbers).

At the moment I'm using this

```
int   Size   NULL
```

I would like to know:

- If NULL value in this case would make sense (I read some article that discourage the use of NULL so I would like if this is the case)
- The value of size should be from 0 to 100000, I would like to know if the datatype `Int` is appropriated.

Please if you consider this question inappropriate just comment, I would remove it from the site.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` is the "correct" approach, but it can make writing queries a pain, because `NULL` won't match any predicate except `IS NULL`. For example, say you want a query that finds all rows that have a size between x and y, but you also want to show rows that don't have any size. Your query will look like this:

```
select * from some_table
where size between x and y or size is null;
```

This can introduce unnecessary complexity, and you also need to deal with how to render a null size.

A better option IMHO is to make the column `NOT NULL` and force the user to input a size. That will simplify both your application and query code.

Don't tell me that customers own a property and don't know how big it is.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid If they are stupid enough to enter this, then let them. Their properties won't appear in size-bases searches. So what? They can't complain - they entered the data. I would probably put validation in the field anyway to prevent accidental entry of too small or negative etc, but as long as it passed basic validation, store it and move on. Don't make the site "too smart", or you'll end up with a mess. Banks don't allow you to enter -$20 as the withdrawal amount at an ATM. People will also accept having to enter a valid size. Site designers are generally too sympathetic to users

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` here is correct, as it specifically means *no value was entered*, which is what you are trying to represent. Any other value would actually have some meaning. For example `0` is a valid value - even though it may not make sense in this context. Specifically setting it to `NULL` means that you are explicitly stating that no value was entered.

As for max int question, from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258271%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

> int
>
> Integer (whole number) data from -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) through 2^31 -
>   1 (2,147,483,647).

Answer (score 2):

> If NULL value in this case would make sense (I read some article that discourage the use of NULL so I would like if this is the case)

`NULL` is fine if you want something that represents a non-value. It's better than making up a different representation (e.g. -1 in numerics or an empty string) for each different datatype. We can't really comment further without seeing the article you read and knowing what argument it was putting forward (and in what context).

> The value of size should be from 0 to 100000, I would like to know if the DataType `int` is appropriated.

It's the most appropriately sized integral type - `tinyint` and `smallint` have lower maximum values than 100000. If you want to be thorough, add a `CHECK` constraint to your table also:

```
CREATE TABLE Properties (
    -- Various Columns
    Size int null,
    constraint CK_Properties_Sizes CHECK (Size between 0 and 100000)
    -- More columns, constraints, etc
)
```